# modal pop up to be displayed when the page is scrolled to 50px

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-4

i had used cookie to store the value when click is done on popup to close after the user clicked on close popup the pop should not show again. but i'm getting on problem on this. popup is opening whenever im scrolling even though i had closed it.

```
<div id="fsModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <button type="button" id="cross-btn" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <div id="desk-view" class="modal-body">
            <div id="pop-up" class="row">   
                <div class="arrow_box side-heading col-xs-5 col-sm-5">
                    <h3>Join the Movement, the newsletter that tackles the justice issues that matter to you most.</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="right-form col-xs-7 col-sm-7">
                    <form class="form-inline subscribe-form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="email-popup" placeholder="Enter your email" name="email-input">
                            <button class="btn-form">Sign up</button>
                        </div>
                    </form> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="mobil-view" class="modal-body">
            <div class="pop">
                <div class="side-heading">
                    <h3>Join the Movement, the newsletter that tackles the justice issues that matter to you most.</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="right-form">
                    <form class="form-inline subscribe-form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="email-popup" placeholder="Enter your email" name="email-input">
                            <button class="btn-form">Sign up</button>
                        </div>
                    </form> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$('#fsModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $.cookie('close_popup' , '10' ,  { expires : 7 });
    });

    var scroll_function = getCookie("close_popup");

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if (scroll_function == " ") {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 50) {
                $("#fsModal").modal('show');
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: are you sure you are getting value into scroll_function after you close popup and scroll to 50

Comment: it is the problem i think i'm not getting the value in it

Comment: why you are using cookies for this, check my ans

Comment: i'm trying to store the click value in cookie.

Comment: ok, try to avid cookies or local storage as long as you can handle the code  by variables.. it create unnecessary http traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using jQuery plugin (jQuery cookies) for this, you can get the same from https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

First set cookies to false on home page load event

```
 Cookies.set('ClosePopUp', 'false'); // set this only on home page load event
```

then you will need to set Cookies on your close model

```
$('#fsModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
     Cookies.set('ClosePopUp', 'true');
    });
```

after on your scroll check the same

```
 $(window).scroll(function(){
            if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 50 && Cookies.get('ClosePopUp') != 'true' ) {
                $("#fsModal").modal('show');
            }else {
 $("#fsModal").modal('hide');
}
    });
```

Finally Remove cookies on your logout..

```
Cookies.remove('ClosePopUp');
```

==== Edit for previous version of Cookies.js =====

First set cookies to false on home page load event

```
$.cookie('ClosePopUp', 'false',{ path: '/' }); // set this only on home page load event
```

then you will need to set Cookies on your close model

```
$('#fsModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
      $.cookie('ClosePopUp', 'true',{ path: '/' });
    });
```

after on your scroll check the same

```
 $(window).scroll(function(){
            if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 50 && $.cookie('ClosePopUp') != 'true' ) {
                $("#fsModal").modal('show');
            }else {
 $("#fsModal").modal('hide');
}
    });
```

Finally remove cookies on your logout..

```
$.removeCookie('ClosePopUp');
```

Comment: its not giving result to me. Popup is not even displayed this time

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: Cookies is not defined
    at (index):658

Comment: make sure you are reference of jQuery Cookie .js file is latest version from the site I've given into comment, you have set the order after jQuery inclusion into project.

Comment: this is my jquery.cookie.js file 
* jQuery Cookie Plugin v1.4.0
 * https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie
 *
 * Copyright 2013 Klaus Hartl
 * Released under the MIT license.
but i cant change this file.

Comment: here is the prob, the api is changed in recent, never mind I'll edit my post for 1.4

Comment: its again getting popup on every page.i think my error is in setting home page load event. can u sugest where to set cookie to false on home page load event.

Comment: $(function (){})

Answer (score 1):

you may like to try this, why you are using cookies for this?

```
var ClosePopUp = false;

$('#fsModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
      ClosePopUp = true;
    });


    $(window).scroll(function(){
            if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 50 && ClosePopUp == false) {
                $("#fsModal").modal('show');
            }else {
 $("#fsModal").modal('hide');
}
    });
```

Comment: the main reason to use cookie is as i'm using this popup in my wordpress site for an project.if i use cookie means the popup will occur only once when user enters into the page.But i have a small problem here. I had implemented the above code then the problem is the popup is showing in every page or post of my website. i want this only to apper once in home page but not for all the pages. Can u help me with this .

Comment: in this case you need to have cookies or local storage, see my alternative ans for your approach..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Html:

```
<input type="hidden" id="is_close" value="0">

<div id="dialog">

</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    scrollPosition = $(this).scrollTop();
  if(scrollPosition > 50 && $('#is_close').val() == 0 )
  {
    $('#dialog').dialog({
      buttons: [
        {
          text: "Close",
          click: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            $('#is_close').val('1');
          }
        }
      ]
    });
  }
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s3da9o98/)

Comment: its bootstrap modal not dialog

Comment: Its just an example, you can use any kind of popup in place of Jquery UI dialog. OP issue is not the type of popup.

Comment: ok but why you need to have hidden input when you can handle it in simple js variable? jst for curiosity..

Comment: popup is getting for every scroll even though i had closed it. Its not working for me.